How do I wire a multi-wire electrical fixture?
Cheap foreign chandelier came with no instructions.
It shipped in 8 sections and the wires for each section feed up into a junction box before  the final wire heads to the ceiling box.
Assumptions

"N" (neutral)/ "L" (load)

"N" to "N" and "L" to "L"  - Each set in its own wire nut.

The last set of "N" & "L" to the black/white power wire.


My assumption is that not all the "N" and "L" wires are wire nutted together.
Can anyone concur?



Where is the ground wire? This appears to be made of metal, so grounding it is critical - if it's not grounded and one of the current-carrying wires touches the shell, someone who touches it could be killed.

...send it back before it burns your house down and voids your insurance coverage, as the "came with no instructions" part is a clue that it has no UL listing. Thus "cheap foreign chandelier" becomes "very expensive foreign chandelier"

Your assumption of "all N together to Neutral", "all L together to Load" is likely correct.
However... if anything ever goes wrong, particularly a fire, you may be in BIG trouble. In most places, any permanently wired fixtures must be certified/listed by an appropriate agency to indicate safe design (and presumably manufactured according to the safe design). In the US, this typically means UL or ETL.
What can go wrong? Very likely nothing will go wrong, because a ceiling fixture doesn't run much risk of shock hazard and LED lighting uses very little power. But some things that could go wrong:

Neutral and ground connected in the fixture. The fixture would work properly but this violates code and could cause problems in certain situations.
Poor connections within the fixture can cause arcing or heating, leading to a fire.
Wires thinner than needed can result in overheating of wires and either a fire or a premature failure of the fixture.
Mechanical design may be such that the fixture could fall apart - and on to someone's head.

And probably a few other things. With plug-in devices there isn't as much of an issue because many problems can be resolved when they start by simply unplugging the device. But with hardwired devices, safe design is critical.

Chemistry and thermal performance of the wire insulation is another common issue with cheap imports. Breaks down with age, not flame resistant, perhaps even "burns very well by itself" etc. Since we see nice copper coloring, copper plated aluminum conductors is another issue.
